# Deleting Specific rows using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to add a `delete` button to my note taking website project I am doing at school. Almost like a forum, where you would delete replies to a topic... I want to be able to delete individual notes. Currently I can delete, however it will only delete the most recent note (bottom of the notes table). How would I get it so the `delete` button deletes the note from the corresponding row, not just the bottom one.

The main interface (Where I believe the problem is)

```
$sql="SELECT noteID, title, note, timestamp FROM $tbl_name WHERE user='$currentuser' AND subject='$currentsubject'";


$result=mysql_query($sql);
?>

<table align="center" id="notes">
<tr>
<td width="10%"><strong>Title</strong></td>
<td width="10%"><strong>ID</strong></td>
<td width="50%"><strong>Note</strong></td>
<td width="10%"><strong>Time</strong></td>
<td width="10%"><strong>Delete</strong></td>
</tr>

<?php

// Start looping table row
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

echo'
<br> 
<tr>
<td>'.$rows['title'].'</td>
<td>'.$rows['noteID'].'</td>
<td>'.$rows['note'].'</td>
<td>'.$rows['timestamp'].'</td> ';
$todelete = $rows['noteID'];
$_SESSION['todelete'] = $todelete;
echo'
<td><form method="post" action="deletenote.php" ><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete" </td> 
</tr>

';
}
ob_end_flush()
?>
```

Comment: Do not use mysql_* functions anymore! It's old, deprecated, unsecure,  removed in php7. Use mysqli or PDO!

Comment: Loop is Overwrite $todelete variable

Comment: I don't see a DELETE FROM ..... so how do we know if that isn't failing also?

Comment: You have a bunch of buttons that all submit the same form. Make sure you somehow pass the id of the note to delete. Also, note that your form is never closed, so you're nesting forms, possibly generating side effects. Lastly, `mysql_query` and other functions from the `mysql_` API are depricated. If you're learning, please learn about an API that is actually in use, like PDO (my suggestion) or mysql*i*_*.

Comment: I also don't see a closing `</form>` tag. Plus, `<form>` cannot be made child of `<table>`.

Comment: either add the id to the action: `action="deletenote.php?id='.$todelete.'"` or add a hidden input to the form: `<input tyoe="hidden" name="noteID" value="'.$todelete.'">`

Comment: @Jeff that's correct but he's using post method and store value in session then pass to deletenote.php

Comment: @Smartpal Yes, but as you've noted the way via session won't work. And a posted form can have a get parameter attached!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way of doing it would be by just providing a delete link for each post:

```
// Start looping table row
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo '<br>';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$rows['title'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$rows['noteID'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$rows['note'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$rows['timestamp'].'</td>';
    echo '<td><a href="//example.com/deletenote.php?id='.$rows['noteID'].'">Delete</a></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Keep in mind that `deletenote.php` would have to verify that the user is signed in and has permission to delete the post.

Comment: Sorted! Legend <3

Answer (score 0):

First of all: where is your corresponding code/query regarding the specific use case (delete note)?

You are trying to submit a form without any parameters, I am assuming you  are trying to use the session variable. However, this variable will always be set to the last loop-iteration. Therefore, I would recommend you to use this code sample:

```
// Start looping table row
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo '<br>';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$rows['title'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$rows['noteID'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$rows['note'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$rows['timestamp'].'</td>';
    echo '<td><form method="post" action="deletenote.php" ><input type="hidden" name="noteID" value="'.$rows['noteID'].'"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete"></form> </td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: May be you're missing name in hidden field.